# How to plot graph with logarithmic y axis

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, fft, logarithm

Zip with `signal.csv`: [FFT](https://ufile.io/h64lh0aj)

I have this Impulse:

[image]

I can create a FFT graph of it with `np.fft.rfft`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('signal.csv')
fft = pd.DataFrame(np.abs(np.fft.rfft(df['1'])))   #y
n = df['0'].size
unit_freq = 1000000000 #Giga
sample_rate = 10000000000   #10 GS/s
freq_sample_fact = sample_rate/unit_freq
freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(n, 1/freq_sample_fact)       #x
fft.index = freq
fft.values[0] = 0
fft.plot(grid = 1,
         color = (255/255,0,0),
         linewidth = 0.3,
         figsize = (10,5),
         legend = False,
         xlim = [fft.index[0], fft.index[-1]*0.8],
         ylim = 0,
         xticks = np.arange(0, freq_sample_fact/2 + 0.1, round(freq_sample_fact/2/10, 1)))
plt.xlabel('Frequenz / GHz')
plt.ylabel('Signalstärke')
plt.title('FFT')
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I plot the y axis logarithmically? When I add

```
plt.semilogy(fft)
```

this happens:

[image]

I want the y axis to represent values from 0 to 20000 logarithmically so that FFT maxima of for example 8000 and 16000 can be compared with each other more comfortably. I hope I could make my point clear.

Comment: Could you try to use `plt.ylim(0.01, 20000)` and `plt.yscale("log")`? It is not possible to set a lower ylim to 0 in a semilog plot, as 0 corresponds to -infty.

Comment: Thanks, the only thing I had to do was remove `ylim=0` from the plot function.